# A ques about promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I just read a [article](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/WJUwKgtl0uAJJfiU9alL3g) about `promise`. And I am really confused.

Why is

```
const bookPromise = bookModel.fetchAll();
const authorPromise = authorModel.fetch(authorId);
const book = await bookPromise;
const author = await authorPromise;
```

is a better way than

```
const books = await bookModel.fetchAll();
const author = await authorModel.fetch(authorId);
```

The author explained that it make the `promise serial execution`. But i justcan not see the difference. Can you explain about this to me. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first snippet, both `Promise`s are declared, and the asynchronous code for both starts running immediately - both network requests (or whatever the operation is) gets sent out immediately. In the second snippet, the `author` Promise does not *start* until the `books` Promise has resolved - if latency is high, for example, that could be a problem. Better to send out both requests at once, rather than requiring one to be completed before starting the other one.

It might be clearer to use `Promise.all` instead, though:

```
const [book, author] = await Promise.all([
  bookModel.fetchAll(),
  authorModel.fetch(authorId)
]);
```